# Possible to change ActionBarSherlock to AppCompat in compiled APK?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, apk, decompiling, smali

I have an actionbar-sherlock app, but just the APK. 
would it be possible to change the actionbar from sherlock to appcompat(support library) or even the normal Android 5.0 actionbar?

When i decompile the app and getting the smali i could get Java code (~) that is more or less correct, then search for the sherlock-things and then change this in the smali code and then backsmali the code to an working APK

Would there be a generell restriction that makes this impossible or would it be possible?

Comment: See [this](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/)

Comment: allready found and studied the article, but that would be with plain Java-code that is editable, but with smali to java code generator you don't get Java code that is 100% correct, so you couldn't recompile it